# Understanding EFE: RHS linear, LHS not?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, non-linear-systems

Einstein's field equations are nonlinear. That means it is not allowed to add up the metric tensors. However, on the RHS of the field equations, there is only the stress-energy-momentum tensor, and it is *allowed* to sum up energies.

Now, I'm wondering:
Is it mathematically *correct* to formulate an equation (edit:a *differential* equation) where the RHS adds up linearly and the LHS doesn't?
Shouldn't it be either both sides add up linearly or both sides *don't* add up linearly?

Comment: "it is allowed to sum up energies." What do you mean by this?

Comment: $x^2=2x$ ... RHS linear, LHS non-linear.

Comment: @Andrew: if they don't interact you can sum up their stress-energy-momentum tensors, can't you?

Comment: @BarrierRemoval:  The stress-energy tensor implicitly depends on the metric, though, which means that you can't add them.  There's no way to keep one source of stress-energy from interacting with the other gravitationally, and vice versa.  (Of course, these interactions might be small, but then we're talking about the linearized limit anyhow.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
x^2 + 1 = x
\end{equation}
The left hand side is nonlinear in $x$, while the right hand side is linear, but this is still a valid equation.

Actually the situation you are talking about is more like this
\begin{eqnarray}
g^2 + 1 &=& T \\
T &=& \frac{\phi^2}{g}
\end{eqnarray}
where $g$, $T$, and $\phi$ are all real numbers in this toy example.
The right hand side of the first equation is linear in $T$ (still a valid equation). The second equation is not linear in $g$ or $\phi$.

To make an analogy with Einstein's equations, $T_{\mu\nu}$ appears linearly in Einstein's equations, but $T_{\mu\nu}$ itself depends non-linearly on the matter fields and on the metric.

For instance, the stress energy tensor of a Klein-Gordon scalar field depends on the inverse metric, and the square of the scalar field. See, eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation#Action.

Comment: First remark: Your example $x^2 +1 = x $ has  _no_ solutions in R. You need complex numbers to get _two_ solutions.

Comment: Second remark: Einstein's field equations are _differential_ equations. They are made to combine _functions_, not numbers. I'm still wondering whether it's ok to combine functions in a differential equation and the LHS is linear while the RHS is non-linear. Your example on numbers doesn't solve my problem, I'm sorry.

Comment: @BarrierRemoval Well, the LHS of EFE looks like $\partial\Gamma + \Gamma^{2}\sim \partial^{2}g + g^{-1}[(\partial g)^{2}]$, which doesn't change anything Andrew says in his post.

Comment: @AlexNelson: where comes your equation from?

Comment: @BarrierRemoval The definition of the Ricci tensor and Christoffel symbols in terms of the metric. The Christoffel symbols are first-order partial derivatives of the metric, the Riemann tensor has the shape sketched, etc.

Comment: @AlexNelson: Thank you! What is $\Gamma$?

Comment: @BarrierRemoval I'm sorry to be this blunt, but you need to learn some more basic mathematics and physics before you are ready to handle general relativity at the level you are asking. And if not, you need to learn to trust people who have studied GR extensively. An example of a differential equation with solutions in $R$ that is nonlinear on the LHS and linear on the RHS is $\dot{x}^2 = x$. The solution is $x(t) = \frac{1}{4}(c_1^2 + \pm 2 c_1 t + t^2)$ where $c_1$ is an integration constant. Here's a link to WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%27%28t%29%5E2+%3D+x%28t%29+for+x

Comment: If you are asking what $\Gamma$ is, then you also clearly didn't read the (free and available online) reference I sent you in a previous question, where I made the same point as Alex Nelson and you asked for a reference.

Comment: @Andrew: Ok, you got me. I started reading though. And, yes, I have to admit that it _is_ indeed hard stuff (yes, I knew before, and yes, many people told me before, too). However, I really enjoy physics.stackexchange and your answers and discussion with you and the community and I am learning a lot. Sorry for probably sometimes being rude or dull-witted.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a small comment to buttress Andrew's answer (since it was a long string of comments on his answer!). Let us review the definitions of basic geometric gadgets used in Einstein's field equations:

The Christoffel symbols are defined as:
\begin{equation}\tag{1a}
\Gamma_{\rho\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\nu\rho}+\partial_{\nu}g_{\mu\rho}-\partial_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu})
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{1b}
{\Gamma^{\sigma}}_{\mu\nu}=g^{\sigma\rho}\Gamma_{\rho\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
where $g^{\sigma\rho}$ is the inverse of the metric tensor. Thus we can intuitively think of the second of these equations, suppressing the indices, as:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\Gamma\sim g^{-1}\partial g.
\end{equation}
(See, e.g., section 3 of Carroll's [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019).)

The Riemann tensor is defined as:
\begin{equation}\tag{3a}
{R^{\rho}}_{\sigma\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}{\Gamma^{\rho}}_{\nu\sigma} -
\partial_{\nu}{\Gamma^{\rho}}_{\mu\sigma} +
{\Gamma^{\rho}}_{\mu\lambda}{\Gamma^{\lambda}}_{\nu\sigma} -
{\Gamma^{\rho}}_{\nu\lambda}{\Gamma^{\lambda}}_{\mu\sigma}.
\end{equation}
The Ricci tensor contracts certain indices:
\begin{equation}\tag{3b}
R_{\sigma\nu} := {R^{\rho}}_{\sigma\rho\nu}.
\end{equation}
We see this looks like, suppressing the indices and using Eqs (2) and (3):
\begin{equation}\tag{4b}
\begin{split}
R &\sim \partial\Gamma + \Gamma\Gamma\\
&\sim \partial(g^{-1}\partial g) + (g^{-1}\partial g)^{2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This is the left-hand side of Einstein's equations, and should make explicitly clear the nonlinear nature of the field equations.

**Note:** this is an attempt to convey the intuitive "locations" of nonlinearity. They are not "subtracted out" in Eq (3a).